# How to debug power devices on Windows?

Tags: windows, hardware, hid

I'm developing a USB HID power device (UPS) and having trouble getting it recognized on Windows - it shows 0% charge even though I'm trying to report 30%.

I tried `powercfg /energy` and the report says that the battery reports no full capacity (see screenshot below). I fixed the issue but am still getting the same report.

My question is: is there a way in Windows to see more details about power devices, potentially logs, reports etc?

[image: error screenshot]

[image: battery info screenshot]

As requested in the comments, adding some details:

- The device in question is a physical one, a Raspberry Pi Pico programmed with TinyUSB. The code is based on this example: https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb/tree/6daa135201b16c287f0b0d7ad7463877d471ceef/examples/device/hid_generic_inout
- I have previously debugged the device on Ubuntu Linux using `upower` to view the reported information and WireShark to monitor USB communication. On Linux, the communication on HID level was working fine, and the cause of my problems were missing fields from report descriptors.

Comment: You're missing a lot of details in your post - such as where/how/why/etc you're defining your HID report descriptors, sending it down the bus, et cetera. Are you doing simulation with a USB traffic-generator in-software or are you using real hardware? What HID chipset are you using? What USB debug hardware do you have? Do you have a protocol-analyzer set-up to see the actual raw USB frames and transactions?

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your comment. I edited the question to include more details and to be more specific what I'm after. Please note though that it is not about fixing this specific problem and not about USB, but rather about power management in Windows and how it handles HID devices. Apologies for not being 100% clear about this.